# Trying to make a simple prime number checker, won't let me use square root. Python 3.2

Tags: python, numbers, primes, square-root

I have a function to check if a number is a square root:

```
def primeness(n):
    for x in range(2, (n**0.5) + 1):
        if n % x == 0:
            return False
    return True
def main():
    n = input('Type a digit \n')
    if primeness(n):
        print(n, 'is a prime number')
    else:
        print(n, 'is not a prime number')
main()
```

However whenever I run it I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Matt/Desktop/Python Stuff/test.py", line 12, in <module>
main()
  File "C:/Users/Matt/Desktop/Python Stuff/test.py", line 8, in main
if primeness(n):
  File "C:/Users/Matt/Desktop/Python Stuff/test.py", line 2, in primeness
for x in range(2, (n**0.5) + 1):
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'str' and 'float'
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You say your testing for square roots but you are testing if the number is prime?

Comment: O.O You've just blown my mind. `n**0.5` is the same as `sqrt(n)`??!!! I never knew that! :D

Comment: @yentup Yeah its a simple mathematical property. the `nth` root of `a` is the same as `a` to the power of `1/n`, so the second (or square) root of a number is that number raised to power of 1/2 or 0.5

Answer (score 5):

in python3, `input` is the equivalent of the old `raw_input`.  Thus you need to perform a cast  and convert it into an integer.

```
def main():
    n = int(input('Type a digit \n')) #right here
    if primeness(n):
        print(n, 'is a prime number')
    else:
        print(n, 'is not a prime number')
```

if you can't guarantee that the string will be an integer, you need to either do some casting, such as `int(float(input()))` or use `try-except` blocks to process the issue.

Answer (score 3):

You must convert from the input string to an int

You may also run into problems with

```
for x in range(2, (n**0.5) + 1):
```

`n ** 0.5` may return a float number while range requires an integer. Fix it by rounding or casting it to an int

Answer (score 1):

`input` returns a string. not an int. You need to convert it first.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to calculate the square root of *n*; you can instead calculate the square of *x*:

```
def primeness(n):
    x = 2
    while x * x <= n:
        if x % n == 0:
            return False
        x = x + 1
    return True
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem. Using sqrt works perfectly under normal circumstances.

Comment: Of course it works perfectly well to take the square root, as long as you don't mind the conversion to and from real numbers. I was merely trying to point out an alternative, since other responses had already answered the question. There's no need for a downvote.

Comment: Ahh, sorry. I didn't know that you posted this after the question had been answered. If you edit the post I'll be able to cancel my down-vote.

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart here you go. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
python 3.2

#change this line:
for x in range(2, int(n**0.5) + 1):
```

Comment: You may want to say what to and why, that way the author knows